# Import Process Interrupted

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

```
Import Failed!
```

I am using astra and starter template "simply nature" but when I go to import complete site, It starting install and activates all the required plug in then shows error on importing content :
" import failed!"
Then click on the given article and increased the following in php.ini
excution_time
memory_limit
Max_input_size etc...
(According to the article I clicked on)
Then again trying to import the complete site and it shows the same error again as earlier.
I don't why its happening while I used it earlier and it has successfully done but this time its not happening !!
I am working on local host
`Please suggest what should I do ?`

Comment: You should search for error log files and check if there you can find more info about the error. We are not able to do it for you on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

step 1:open xampp go to apache>config>PHP(php.ini)

step 2:In notepad file search for word execution. You can see this line there

**"
Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time=120      "**

step3: change your execution time from 120 to 180(if its 30 then change to 120)

step 4: save the file. stop apache and mysql and restart both. Refresh your wordpress page and again try to import the templates. Hope you get success